# How to take get element in css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, queryselector

I'm not sure that there is unique question, but i can't find the same, sorry. Can u please help me to take element from DOM using CSS to apply style for it. i have similar block

```
  <div class="parent-block">
    <div class="child accomplished">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-block">
    <div class="child accomplished">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-block">
    <div class="child null">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-block">
    <div class="child null">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So i need to take last child with class accomplished. I can't use nth-child because it's dynamically blocks and it can be a lot of parent blocks with accomplished.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the js or jquery?

Comment: i'm using react

Comment: react and js compatible

Comment: U are right. For current time i used querySelector, but it's bad practise for access to DOM from component.

Comment: use `document.getElemesntsByClassName`, `document.getElemesntById`

Comment: for react - `componentDidMount() { this.go = document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[0] }`

Answer (score 3):

See [the selectors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/).

The only `:last` pseudo-classes are keyed off *every* sibling an element has or every sibling of the same *type*.

There is nothing along the lines of  `:last-of-class`.

---

You need to use JS to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery to select your required element.

Use the following sytax:

`$(selector).action()`

So here you could use:

`$(".child acomplished").last().css("border", "3px solid red")`

Take a look at the w3 schools docs to see how to add JQuery to your project:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: jquery is not suitable for the author because he uses react.js library, but your answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

Use
For the first element :

document.getElemesntsByClassName("parent-block")[0].style.color = "#fff";

For the last element

document.getElemesntsByClassName("parent-block")[3].style.color = "#fff";